# R codes for AIC in distribution fitting

Tags: r, statistics, weibull, gamma-distribution

I have fitted the Weibull, lognormal and Gamma distributions to my claim amount data using the `fitdistr` in R. I want to choose which one fits my sample data the best using the `AIC` in R. How do I proceed?

Comment: Please include the code that you've tried so far.  What is not working for you?  In the event that you're completely unsure of how to proceed, Googling for `R fitdistr AIC` returned several promising results.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `AIC` function:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rlnorm(100) # random values from a log-normal distribution

# fit distributions
library(MASS)
weibull <- fitdistr(x, "weibull")
lognormal <- fitdistr(x, "lognormal")
gamma <- fitdistr(x, "gamma")

# compare AICs
AIC(weibull)
# [1] 300.9519
AIC(lognormal)
# [1] 287.0875
AIC(gamma)
# [1] 297.1818
```

Not surprisingly, the log-normal fit has the *lowest* AIC. This is the best fit.